# PHP socket send message in Korean or Asian Language

Tags: php

I want know how can we send a message in Asian language, such as Korean using php socket. I am already sending and receiving English characters. I look at the in wire Shark to see what I am sending, to see if i am sending correctly. 
Note: (I do not speak any Korean this is just a test)
Already tried to change data to binary:  `hex2bin(sprintf("%%c", ("ㅁ")));`

```
        // $data= "This is test"; 
        $data= "ㅁ"; 
         if (!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))) {
            $errorcode = socket_last_error();
            $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

            return("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg ");
        }

        //Connect socket to remote server
        if (!socket_connect($sock, $address, $port)) {
            $errorcode = socket_last_error();
            $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

            return("Could not connect: [$errorcode] $errormsg ");
        }
     if (!socket_send($sock, $data, strlen($data), 0)) {
            $errorcode = socket_last_error();
            $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

            return("Could not send data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
        }
        //Now receive reply from server
        if (($byte = socket_recv($sock, $buf, 2045, 0)) === FALSE) {
            $errorcode = socket_last_error();
            $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
            return("Could not receive data: [$errorcode] $errormsg");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research below solutions worked for me.

```
$data = mb_convert_encoding("바베큐돼지등갈비", "EUC-KR","utf-8");
```

Comment: Sockets don't speak human languages. They transfer bytes. That's why we have protocols that we use to format those bytes. You could have just used `json_encode` on this and you'd get a proper UTF8. Anyway, your answer, while helpful for you, is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you I will go head and test json_encode and I will let your know the result

Comment: Don't worry, just try to find what the standards are for exchanging messages via sockets and implement one of those. If I were you, I'd use `json_encode()` for serialization and `json_decode` for deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the mail's headers array:

```
"Content-type: text/html; charset=EUC-KR\r\n"
```